# Combine syntax highlighting of different Eclipse editors

Tags: eclipse, r, syntax-highlighting, sweave, statet

I use Eclipse, StatET and the Sweave plugin to write my R and Latex code. The cool thing is that R and Latex code can be put together into one file, however you end up with a syntax highlighting problem.

I have loads of R code and I very much like the Eclipse R syntax highlighting. But now combining R and Latex means that I have to work with .Rnw files where there is no particular syntax highlighting for R.

When I go to Eclipse -> Preferences -> Content Types I can add *.Rnw to "R script file" which makes Eclipse to open the .Rnw files with the standard R Editor. However, this means that I do not have syntax highlighting for Sweave any longer. In addition, the Sweave code is shown as an error in the R editor.

My question is whether it is possible to combine different syntax highlighting styles in an easy way?

Comment: It works fine for me, and I don't recall having done anything special. All of my R code chunks inside .rnw files are highlighted as expected.

Comment: I reinstalled my StatET and now syntax highlighting in the .Rnw file works for me now too. Don't know what was wrong. I played around a lot with all of the settings maybe I set some wrong parameters. But what still remains is that in the .Rnw files you do not have auto-completion for the R commands. For instance, if you type libr and then press CTRL+Space it gives you the possibility to add library() which is not the case in the .Rnw file. What a shame :(

Comment: I "solved" this by writing code in a separate file and once it's production grade, I copy paste it into a Sweave chunk.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think any Eclipse plugins/editors really support mixing up several syntaxes inside one editor. At any rate it is not currently supported in Eclipse Platform.

However you can try [Eclipse Colorer](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/eclipsecolorer/index.html) plugin. It allows to switch coloring style for the current editor. It may mot support both R and Latex syntax, but you can create your own highlighting by adding your own [HRC file](http://colorer.sourceforge.net/hrc-ref/index.html).

Comment: hm ok I am just wondering how people over come such problems then. I don't really think I am the first one who discovered that. But maybe they really just create there own highlighting.